# SOQL Accounts with No Cases in last 12 Months

Tags: soql

I'm having trouble querying accounts with no cases for the last 12 months. Using the query below, I feel like I'm close to the solution, but not quite. Can someone assist?

```
SELECT Id, Name, IsClient__c, Account_Status__c
FROM Account 
WHERE Account_Status__c = 'Active'
AND IsClient__c = true
AND Id not In (select accountid from case)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of one of the [SOQL Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) here.

Specifically, `LAST_N_MONTHS:n` (replacing 'n' with 12)

The only line that would need to change in your query is the last line (the one doing the anti-join)

`AND Id NOT IN (SELECT accountid FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:12)`

Comment: Thank you so much. One correction, however. You might want to edit your reply and remove the comma after accountid. Other than that, thanks a mil!

Comment: You're welcome, and fix'd. I was just copy/pasta-ing from your question though, so just double check that the same error isn't in your actual code too.